# "?" operator in javascript applied to an example in d3

Tags: d3.js

I've been struggling to understand how [Zoomable treemap example by Mike Bostock](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/) works.

I went to the [API reference of treemap](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Treemap-Layout), understood the basic way of working.
I got lost when I tried to understand the custom implementation shown in the previous link.

I think I understand the way it expects hierarchically structured .json data. As a user I saw it does the recursive calls  to unlimited "depth" data but going line by line I don't understand this:

```
`var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
.children(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d.children; })
...
`
```

What is the general meaning of `"?"`? What does `"?"` mean there? Does it return the `depth` of the node? i.e. 0 means root, 1 means child...

It also appears in other functions, like the one that accumulates (that I dont understand either what it does)

```
`function accumulate(d) {
return d.children
? d.value = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
: d.value;
`
```

Or the one that shows the name

```
`function name(d) {
return d.parent
? name(d.parent) + "." + d.name
: d.name;
}
 `
```

I'd appreciate your help to make me understand what's going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` operator is a general Javascript construct for conditions. That is,

```
foo ? 0 : 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
if(foo) {
  0
} else {
  1
}
```

It's a shorter way to write conditional statements.

Comment: I knew it would be a simple solution, but I did not imagine I'd be so basic. Thank you

Comment: @PleaseTeachMeHowToDoIt Just for future reference, the technical name for it is a [**`Ternary operator`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), which signals an shorthand syntax of an `if()` as `?:`